# mongodb query to get time stamp

Tags: mongodb

currently I am learning mongodb.

I have a collection  called listings and I want to search a "text" from description field. I want my query to show only text not all the information in the document.

I have created a text index for description field with following command

```
db.listings.ensureIndex( { description: "text" } )
```

when I search string "marketing" I am getting all the information in the document. but want to get just marketing word and time stamp with that for analytical purpose. I can count how many time it is been used but how can I know time stamp with that word "marketing"

```
db.listings.find( { $text: { $search: "marketing" } } ).count()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example doc that shows your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.listings.find({$text: {$search: "marketting"}}, {text:1, timestamp: 1}).pretty()
```